# Why use gloves when handling food?

Tags: food-safety, food-processing

I watched this video yesterday https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2LerF1zgRDE . (Its a video that the manufacturer shows how they make candy and in this case its also seen they work the candy with naked hands). And reading the comments most people were shocked that they do not use gloves for (consumer health reasons). Chefs don't use gloves when working with food which in this case should be seen as the same as candy.

It doesn't bug people (as much) when people at restaurants working with your food do not wear gloves. Yet when a manufacturer touches food or candy its frowned on.

So how dangerous is it really to the consumer if who ever is working with your food or candy touches it with their naked hands, if they practice good hygiene (disinfecting hands) ?

Comment: My understanding is that the reason for gloves is often to forgo washing -- when you're changing between meat and vegetables, you can change gloves faster than scrubbing up.  When you're in a factory making just one thing, if you don't have any open wounds and aren't exceptionally hairy, washing your hands is generally sufficient.  (although local health codes have the final say on this).  And gloves don't stop someone from touching their face and then touching the food, so they aren't automatically hygienic if you have someone w/ bad practices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am afraid that gloves make things worse. Even with proper training, people who wear gloves seem to be more complacent that those who do not wear gloves. I have seen people handle dollar bills then turn around and touch my food with the same gloves on. Disgusting, and I refuse the food, and when I tell them why, they say the gloves are to protect me...what the F ever. Then I ask them how that glove protects me
From
The germs on those dollars you just touched?

I find its better to enforce good hand washing habits than it is to allow gloves to be used at all. When you are wearing gloves, you don't even wipe your hand on a towel, without gloves your hands kinda start to tell you they need to be washed if you've been lax.